# Photoshop, I can't see any size or number info

Tags: adobe-photoshop, measurement

I am using Adobe Photoshop CC, but when I draw a shape or making guide or using marquee tool, I can't see a number/size measurement info.

Anyone know how to fix it.

[image: e]

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to say. There's nothing missing in the screenshot as far as I can tell. Are you perhaps talking about the `Preferences > Tools > Show transformation values`? If you want to make make a specific size graphic, whatever it may be, there are better ways than just eyeing it using that transformation values floater. One place to check selection size or layer size is the `Window > Info` panel.

Comment: I would like to point out that while the file is embedded with a conversion factor, and each unit either represent that or number of pixels. A image on a computer does not inherently have a size.

Answer (score 2):

Open the *Info Panel* by selecting *Window > Info*.

Make sure to choose the *Ruler Units* you want in *Panel Options* in the upper right corner of the panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I can't see Ruler Units in Panel Options.

Comment: Ok, I've added a screenshot. But be careful with physical units. They are dependent on the resolution of your image and if the setting is wrong/random or you later resize the image in a layout program, they won't be correct anymore. I hardly ever measure anything else than pixels in Photoshop. If I need something at a certain physical size I use a vector based layout program like InDesign or Illustrator.